# nginx remove / rewrite GET Parameters for specific URL

Tags: regex, nginx, location, url-rewriting

I want to create a nginx localtion do to the following

*Given URL:*

***example.com/foo/bar/123456?ItemID=123456&aid=0&bid=0***

*Task:*

If both numbers are the same and aid and bid are zero, then rewreite the url to ***example.com/foo/bar/123456***

*My Try:*

```
location ~ ^/foo/bar/(?<prid>\d+)\?ItemID=\1&aid=0&bid=0$ {
  rewrite ^ /foo/bar/$prid? permanent;
}
```

But that doesn't work. ;)

Would be great if s.o. could give me a hint.

**EDIT:**

nginx seems not to match GET-Parameters by regex at all (in location line) so you have to use $args and check with if (which can be evil according to documentation).

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
    location ~ /foo/bar/(\d+) {
        if ($arg_ItemID = $1)   { set $check I; }
        if ($arg_aid = 0)   { set $check "${check}A"; }
        if ($arg_bid = 0)   { set $check "${check}B"; }
        if ($check = IAB) {
            rewrite ^ /foo/bar/$arg_ItemID? permanent;
    }   }
```

Explanation:

- nginx doesn't include the parameters in the match for rewrite. You can access the parameters by name via `$arg_name`.
- the set of `if`-statements is a work-around (described [here](https://gist.github.com/jrom/1760790)), because nginx doesn't allow multiple conditions
- the `?` at the end of the replacement cuts off the arguments from the original request

Comment: Hey Carsten, tried that but nginx seems not to match GET-Parameters by regex at all (in location line) so you have to use $args and check with if (which can be evil according to documentation).

Comment: I wasn't able to get the back reference match to work: `ItemID=$1` I'm running nginx/1.7.12.